# Passing openpyxl Workbook object with multi-processing in python

Tags: python, openpyxl, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to write a piece code to pass a workbook to create multiple process using python multiprocessing library. When I am trying to run the code, I'm getting the below error.

*'MemoryError
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "C:\Users\ajit_kumar_kompalli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
File "C:\Users\ajit_kumar_kompalli\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input*'

Here's my code.

```
batch_files_path = r"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Test\"
master_file = r"C:\Users\admin\Desktop\Test\Master.xlsm"
fwbk = load_workbook(master_file)
ws_WF = fwbk['Workflow']

for count in range(3, len(ws_WF['A']) + 1):
    if ws_WF.cell(row=count, column=2).value not in d_batch_type:
        d_batch_type[ws_WF.cell(row=count, column=2).value] = ws_WF.cell(row=count, column=3).value

#Generating the Batch - Index Dictionary - Array for operations
d_batch_index = {batch: [] for batch in d_batch_type}
for batch in d_batch_type:
    for count in range(3, len(ws_WF['A']) + 1):
        if str(batch) == str(ws_WF.cell(row=count,column=2).value):
            d_batch_index[batch].append(ws_WF.cell(row=count,column=1).value)

jobs=[]
for batch in d_batch_index:
    final_path = batch_files_path + str(batch) + '_Test.xlsx'
    if d_batch_type[batch] == 'Weights':
        process = multiprocessing.Process(name=batch,target=generate_weighted_worksheet, args=(fwbk, final_path))
        jobs.append(process)

    elif d_batch_type[batch] == 'AWF':
        process = multiprocessing.Process(name=batch,target=generate_awf_worksheet, args=(fwbk, final_path))
        jobs.append(process)

process = multiprocessing.Process(name='pse_ops', target=generate_pse_ops_worksheet,
                                  args=(fwbk, pseops_output_path))
jobs.append(process)

for j in jobs:
    logging.debug("Starting the process: {}".format(j))
    j.start()
    print("Starting the process: {} pid:{}".format(j,j.pid))

for j in jobs:
    logging.debug("Joining the process: {} under main".format(j))
    j.join()
```

The functions generate_weighted_worksheet, generate_awf_worksheet, generate_pse_ops_worksheet use fwbk as an input. So I want to pass that fwbk variable. I understand that python multi-processing allocates new memory and make a copy of the passed objects/variables. But I'm not sure what exactly is this issue. Please help.

Comment: In the first line, you are escaping (`\`) the end quote (`"`). That might be causing the issue?

Comment: The code throws an error on starting the jobs in for loop. Its something related to pickle load error. I'm not exactly sure on what it is and how to handle it.